# How to make the key combination "win" + "." send the instruction to media_next?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

How do I make the key combination <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> send the instruction to `media_next`?

I have tried writing in several different ways but I always get a script error.

My objective is to press the keys <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> and have the music players skip to the next track.

Please tell me the exact sentence as I'm completely new to scripting and one character missing, for example, will be a huge obstacle for me...

Not so important: should I be writing these instructions in `autohotkey.ahk` or in `shortcuts.ahk`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working? What error messages are showing? What media program are you trying to work with? What instruction are you trying to send? According to a brief perusal of the Autohotkey docs, `media_next` is not a valid command...

Comment: @darthbith, [sure it is](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

Comment: Well, `media_next` isn't a command on its own, but `Send {media_next}` is. I do agree with @darthbith that questioners should generally show that they have tried to solve the question themselves, and explain what they've done.

Comment: @Dane, cybergofer never said anything about a media_next “command”; they were clearly asking about remapping `Win+.` to the Media_Next key. Nevertheless, see my answer below; `media_next` may not be a “command”, but it works like one in this context.

Comment: Any particular reason you want that specific hotkey to be mapped to media-next? It seems like kind of an key for this purpose, yet you’re [not the first to request it](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130903084241AAIVRnX). ಠ_ఠ

Comment: I got a little lost trying to answer everyone fast and I missed this question from Synetech. The reason why I chose this specific combination and possibly the reason why it isn't the first time you've seen it is because I have inspired my choice, or I "plagiarized" it from a webpage, very possibly from this website, but I can't remember for sure right now heheheh). I saw somewhere that you could use the Win key combined with others and it sounded good at the time since it's a big key and it's also very close and easy to hit. The "." was probably also there. :). Thank you very much!

Comment: @Synetech looks like it's the same person who asked on YA.

Comment: Yep! That's me! :) I thought I wasn't going to get an answer for that question on YA and so I decided to try here ;)

Comment: @Bob, yes it is. Actually last night it occurred to me to check if it’s the same person **two seconds after I shutdown** (as usual). `¬_¬`

Answer (score 2):

This should work (I tested it with VLC and XMPlay):

```
#.::Media_Next
```

It sends the media-next key to just the active window, so if you want to use the hotkey while watching a full-screen movie or something, it would do the trick. If you are watching a video in the corner of the screen while working on other things, then you’ll need to send the key globally:

```
#.::Send {Media_Next}
```

Of course your media-player must be able to detect and respond to the actual media keys. Some are written to do so by default, some you can set to do so in their key-mapping configuration, others do so automatically when they have the appropriate file-type associations.

As Sonamor pointed out, you can target the hotkey to specific windows in case you have multiple media-players running that all respond to the media-keys (though in my experience, the first one that runs tends to register the key and thus block others from receiving it; so you could just shut them all down and run the one you want).

---

In response to the [more detailed question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130903084241AAIVRnX)…

> I keep trying and I always get error. This is what I've tried the last time:
>
> ```
> LWin + ,::{Media_Next}
> ```
>
> I've also tried:
>
> ```
> Win + .::Media_Next
> ```

There’s several things wrong with those lines:

- The `+` denotes the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key, so the hotkey only work when <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> is held down
- The `;` is the <kbd>;</kbd> key, so it only works when the <kbd>;</kbd> key is held down
- You can’t use `{Media_Next}` as the operation, you can use either:

  - `Send {Media_Next}` to send the media-next key in general
    or
  - `Media_Next` to send the media-next key to just the active window
- `Win` is not valid, you need to use `#` as a modifier
- `LWin` is only valid to use <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> the hotkey. As a modifier, you must use `<#`.

So in your case, you probably want this:

```
<#.::Send {Media_Next}
```

> *I only have one "win" key on my keyboard.

Then why make it specific to the left Windows key? If there’s only one, then it makes no difference which you specify. In fact, it is safer to just use the generic version in case for some reason, the manufacturer decided to use the scancode for the other key. You may as well just use this:

```
#.::Send {Media_Next}
```

Comment: Whoa! I just checked this out and it blew me away. It looks like any named key can be handled this way. I'm going to have to experiment some more...

Comment: @Dane: I haven't tried that one yet. Thanks! Sorry about not having my previous attempts recorded but, at the time, I didn't think I would be needing them especially after finding out they had errors Thank you very much!

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! :) . Again, sorry for commenting for thanking but I had to. That was exactly what I was looking for (skipping tracks while working on other stuff):) Thank you Synetech!

Comment: That information about other media-players will very likely come in handy!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line to your autohotkey.ahk file, save, and then right-click on the AutoHotKey icon in your tray select, Reload This Script:

```
#.::Send {Media_Next}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dane! That way I don't have to have two scrips on the system tray heheh :)! Thank you very much everyone!

Comment: I've managed to recover two of my past failed attempts (just as a curiosity now since the problem is solved :)

LWin + ,::{Media_Next}

I've also tried: 

Win + .::Media_Next

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: So, it looks like the main thing was using `#.` instead of `Win + .`

Comment: It looks like that was the problem (on those two tries. There were probably other different problems with all the others) heheh. This Autohotkey software is great! This is my first experience with scripting and I'm loving it. All the potential for doing other practical stuff :)

Comment: I've become a big fan of AutoHotKey. I started with a few hotstrings for phrases and some hotkey shortcuts, but have now added some more advanced features (plain-text paste, Google highlighted text) and am attempting to grasp some even more complex things like parsing text and sizing/placing windows.

Comment: It really is a fantastic piece of software! small yet powerful!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the AutoIt3 Window Spy and make the hotkey work only for VLC Media Player

```
#IfWinActive, VLCWINDOW
#.::Media_Next
```

Comment: I thought we wanted it for VLC, my bad, but he got the point to make the Hotkey work for certain application.

Comment: Wow this was fast! Thank you very much for your answers!

@darthbith: I've tried and deleted so many of my ignorant attempts to write the correct script. It must have been more than 10 different combinations. But unfortunately, I can't remember exactly what I've tried. This is my last attempt: #.::{Media_Next} Thank you very much!

Comment: Problem solved! 

Thank you very much Sonamor, it looks like   #.::Media_Next   works perfectly! Sorry about answering to thank you but I just can't be ungrateful :)

Comment: Yes, Sonamor, I'm using it to skip tracks on Spotify. Sorry about not being more informative from scratch :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok then use AutoIt3 Window Spy to find the Window name for Spotify, if you want the hotkey to work only if Spotify is focused or dont use the first line of the code if you want the hotkey to be universal.

Comment: That is definitely useful! In this case I want this key combination to work with all media players but I will eventually come across a situation where I will need this :) Thanks!